# Redirecting a specific page to another domain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-301

I recently created a new site on a different domain. I need to redirect the `index.html` of the old domain to the index of the new domain.

Usually this would not be a problem, but the old domain is the root domain of the server, the new one is an add on. So the following line would cause a redirect loop because it redirects `a.com/index.html` and `b.com/index.html` to `b.com/index.html`.

```
Redirect 301 /index.html http://b.com/
```

Is there a way of doing something like this?

```
Redirect 301 http://a.com/index.html http://b.com/
```

**TL;DR** How can I redirect `index.html` on one domain to another domain without it cascading and causing a loop because the other domain is a add on domain (i.e. in the same folder therefor under the law of the same `.htaccess`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try mod_rewrite for more flexibility with the code like this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

# for HTTP
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^a\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =80
RewriteRule ^(index\.html)$ http://b.com/$1 [R=301,L,NC]

# for HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^a\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =443
RewriteRule ^(index\.html)$ https://b.com/$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

Comment: Looks promising, although I am getting a server error when adding symlinks. Any ideas why this might be? Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: Can you please explain what type of symlinks are you creating? Is it symbolic link that we have on *nix systems? Also can you also report relevant error from your error.log as well when you see server error in browser.

Comment: I mean the options line in your example. When including the follow symlinks option my server just dies with no useful error information. Without it, nothing happens.

Comment: You will need to make sure that .htaccess is enabled first in your Apache config otherwise this code is ignored by Apache.

Comment: Okay I managed to fix it with this, any other commands where being ignored.

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^a\.co\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ http://b.co.uk/ [L]

Answer (score 0):

JAVASCRIPT REDIRECT:

Paste this at the top of your page on the old site just after the `<head>` tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.location = "http://www.newsite.com/"
</script>
```

Naturally, you'd replace "http://www.newsite.com/" with wherever you wanted the page to redirect to.

It should redirect you instantly. So anyone visiting the old site page will instantly redirect to newsite.com

PHP REDIRECT (301, permanently moved):

```
<?
Header( "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently" ); 
Header( "Location: http://www.newsite.com/" ); 
?>
```

Place that at the top of your page. It isn't as nice as the javascript one, but it is SEO FRIENDLY, which I think you're looking for.

Comment: Yep, I am sure this would work but I need it to be a 301 redirect.

Comment: I'e updated my answer to include a search-engine friendly redirect method by setting headers with php.

Comment: I have gone with the .htaccess method, your second answer was closer but I am redirecting a html file to the PHP would not be parsed. Thank you anyway.